# Retrofit throwing time out exception while Deserialization

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-architecture-components

I am trying to learn retrofit.I Need to handle deserialization error through retrofit.When any key data type mismatched retrofit throwing timeout exception.

//Retrofit initialization

```
  Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ConstantUtils.BASE_URL)
            .client(getOkHttpClient())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGson()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(new LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
            .build()
            .create(CustomRetrofit.class);

 private Gson getGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(new GsonFieldExclusionStrategy())
                .setLenient()
                .create();
    }
private OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Timber.i(message));
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
}
```

Adding the CallAdapter

```
    public class LiveDataCallAdapter<R> implements CallAdapter<R, LiveData<ApiResponse<R>>> {
    private final Type responseType;

    LiveDataCallAdapter(Type responseType) {
        this.responseType = responseType;
    }

    @Override
    public Type responseType() {
        return responseType;
    }

    @Override
    public LiveData<ApiResponse<R>> adapt(@NonNull Call<R> call) {
        return new LiveData<ApiResponse<R>>() {
            AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean(false);

            @Override
            protected void onActive() {
                super.onActive();
                Timber.d("Live Data Call Adapter Called");
                if (started.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<R>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<R> call, @NonNull Response<R> response) {
                            postValue(new ApiResponse<>(response));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<R> call, @NonNull Throwable throwable) {
                            postValue(new ApiResponse<R>(throwable));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Json String

```
`{
  "sessionID": "201803181521354596165495",
  "name": "Umesh  Saraswat",
  "firstName": "Umesh - MRN:251729",
  "isCorporate": "",
  "access_token": "99f52c9aaba84283fa4b3581f17f3d10",
  "session_timeout": 86400,
  "lastlogin": "16-Mar-2018 11:17 AM",
  "eWellnessPackage": "[]",
  "eWellnessPackageStatus": 0,
  "customerReferralCode": "US305691",
  "cart_order_data": null
}`
```

Model Class

```
 public class LoginAndRegistrationResponse {
    @SerializedName("sessionID")
    private String sessionId;
    private String name;
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    private String accessToken;
    @SerializedName("lastlogin")
    private String lastLoginDateAndTime;
    private Integer eWellnessPackageStatus;
    private String customerReferralCode;
    private String status;
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("msg")
    private String message;;
}
```

When I am using the Model like above. But when I changed the "access-token" to Integer then retrofit  throwing Timeout exception. Now I am confused that time out exception is present due to low internet connectivity  or while Deserialization the Json.

Comment: access token is string...so you should use string not integer.. !! ( while deserialization the json )

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure why it's giving `TimeoutException`. Maybe try increasing the timeout using:

```
@Provides
fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    builder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    builder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    builder.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    return builder.build()
}
```

But as [Santanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7258332/santanu-sur) pointed out the JSON structure is returning `access_token` as `String` and while your `accessToken` is `int` which will not work **directly**.